# Windows `chksdk` errors - (696e647863686b2e 939)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I'm having some issues with a hard disk on my Windows machine. After the system tries to access the disk, or perhaps certain sectors on the disk, the disk "disconnects" and is no longer visible to the OS. If I reconnect by plugging the SATA back in, the disk is recognized. I can browse some files, but again the disk "disappears". I have tried to run the `chkdsk` program on Windows, but I also get errors:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk /r E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N)y
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  656640 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  3320 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
A disk read error occurredc000009d
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 64208.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the bitmap for index $I30 for file 64208.
Sorting index $I30 in file 64208.
An unspecified error occurred (696e647863686b2e 939).
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 1583).
```

I've also tried to just clone the disk image with Macrium and with a bootable Clonezilla USB. Is there any way for me to either 1) fix what is wrong with the disk or 2) get the data off of it? I have other disks that I could write the data to, but I haven't been able to get the data off.

Comment: Can you specify what make and model of drive? This sounds like a Seagate issue I've seen before. You need a low level tool like ddrescue or diskpatch to clone a bad drive. Both are made to work with bad sectors. If you suspect the drive is failing, which it sounds as if it is, you don't want to keep trying chkdsk on it. Clone it asap with the proper tools. Run chkdsk on the cloned copy. If it's Seagate you may have serious troubles because they will shut down every time they hit a bad spot, which could be hundreds or thousands of times during a clone.

Comment: It's a Seagate "Barracuda" 1TB model, and it's fairly old, I think around 5 years. Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it. Do you know where I can find ddrescue, and a guide for using it? Thanks

Comment: Here's a pretty good article on it: https://www.data-medics.com/forum/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue-t133.html. This is not a simple process. Unfortunately I can almost guarantee you won't be able to clone this drive without significant work. The drive will quit reading every time it hits a bad sector which requires power cycling the drive and restarting the clone where it left off. I built a drive bay with USB relay to automatically power cycle Seagate drives during a clone when a failure was detected. Have fun and learn, but don't risk critical data.

Comment: Thank you, I'll post later to let you know how it goes. I'll start tomorrow

Comment: You can try this command *chkdsk c: \f* or r ( /F Fixes errors on the disk, /R Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information )